# How exactly are the password hashing functions in the pgcrypto module different from the regular MD5 and other algorithms?

Tags: postgresql, encryption, hashing, pgcrypto

This is not technically a database question, but about the innards of Postgres's [pgcrypto extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html#id-1.11.7.37.8).The documentation says

> The algorithms in crypt() differ from the usual MD5 or SHA1 hashing
> algorithms in the following respects:

I would like to know how/where might I be able to find the details of the hashing algorithms.

Ideally, I would like to compare the algorithms of pgcrypto with the regular versions of the algorithms.

Comment: The docs are describing the difference between password hashing and other hashing not suitable for password.  Not the difference between their password hashing and other's password hashing.

Comment: This is very much a database question. Password security *inter alia* is integral to database systems and questions related to RDBMS crypto libraries are very much **on topic!** Mostly directed at the person who downvoted without leaving a comment!

Answer (score 1):

Since [Postgresql](https://github.com/postgres/postgres) is open source, you can find the code of hashing algorithms easily.

Basically, [pg_crypt](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/contrib/pgcrypto/pgcrypto.c) function calls [px_crypt](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/contrib/pgcrypto/px-crypt.c) function which picks algoritm and calls related hashing function for example [px_crypt_md5](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/contrib/pgcrypto/crypt-md5.c) which is imported from [FreeBSD](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-src/blob/main/lib/libcrypt/crypt-md5.c) source.

Comment: I think it's the **modifications** that PostgreSQL may have made to the algorithms (as outlined in the link) that the OP is interested in, rather than the "raw" algorithms themselves - at least, that's what I get from the question!

Comment: I tough the same but still this answer may help him

Comment: @Vérace Yes, exactly, it is the Postgres specific modifications to the algorithms that I am interested in.

Comment: @dakini  You haven't specified the *reference* implementations, so how can anyone describe how pgcrypto differs from them?

Comment: @jjanes You're right. The documentation only says *differ from the usual*. It is something I would also like some clarity on.

Comment: @dakini each crpty function has a loop to waste some time . for example there is a loop (`for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++)` ) in md5 and another one in sha512 (`for (cnt = 0; cnt < rounds; ++cnt)`)

Comment: Hi @SahapAsci, Thanks a lot for checking this up! If this is indeed the case, then an easy way to subvert this security measure is by simply rewriting the code without that loop - because it doesn't affect the actual hashing function. I would imagine a more effective means to "time wasting" to be simply repeated hashing. Would you please be kind enough to share the git url/path of the code? I am not familiar enough with the Postgres to start a deep dive from scratch. So any pointers about which files to look in would be appreciated.

Comment: An attacker who has read access to the password hashes can simply copy those hashes onto a different machine and using a non-time-wasting algorithm (without loss of functionality) to brute force it. So this whole measure of adding dummy loops seems quite pointless, imho.

Comment: @dakini the answer already has the code link for `px_crypt_md5` just check the folder for others

Comment: @SahapAsci On closer look, those aren't empty time wasting loops, there's quite some processing going on inside the loops. Because of this, it is not realistic to rewrite the algorithms without those loops and get the same result. I think that's the answer. Thanks for helping out!